# Loop through words in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I've seen a lot of javascript stack questions around this, but nothing specifically related to SQL Server.

What I need to do is accept a string value and do a loop over the string multiple times to get back all the individual words so I can do calculations on them.

A rough idea is shown below. Anyone know how this can be achieved?

```
Declare @String nvarchar(50) = 'Mary had a little lamb'
Declare @word nvarchar(50) 

Start Loop 1 to 5 
    Set @word = 'Mary' (1)
    Set @word = 'had' (2)
    Set @word = 'a' (3)
    Set @word = 'little' (4)
    Set @word = 'lamb' (5)
End Loop
```

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server split string".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to do the job.

```
DECLARE @tags NVARCHAR(400) = 'mary had a little lamb'  

SELECT value  
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tags, ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the parameter and write it in a temp table, and then use the values from the temp table. Using loops in SQL is not the best idea as they really affects your query performance.

```
Declare @String nvarchar(50) = 'Mary had a little lamb'

INSERT INTO #tempTable(colName)
SELECT colName
FROM dbo.Split(@String , ' ')
```